# for loop in thymeleaf

Tags: html, loops, each, thymeleaf

How can I do the following (java):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 81 ; i+=20){
   //Should loop through 5 times!
}
```

in Thymeleaf?

I've tried this:

```
<option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 81/20)}">
   <p th:text="${ i }"></p> <!-- THIS loops 4 times, instead of 5 -->
</option>
```

The problem is that it is not as accurate as the java piece of code. How to do this?

Comment: ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 81/20)} -> What is this. Does this internally tells that it is to be run over this range OR is it something we are explicitly mentioning somewhere

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add step to your code is quite easy.

```
#{numbers.sequence(0, 81, 20)}
```

Answer (score 13):

use **iterStat** key word to iterate. Example
If you have an Array of String and you are iterating the same using thymeleaf.

```
<div th:each="str,iterStat : strings">
   <span th:text="${str}"/><!--This will print the index value-->
   <span th:text="${iterStat.index}"/><!--This will print the Index-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming this is due to the numbers you are using. For your java code,
    int i = 0; i < 81 ; i+=20
will return i=0, i=20, i=40, i=60 and i=80

however your following code
    numbers.sequence( 1, 81/20)}
should returns the integers from 1 to 4.05, being 1, 2, 3, and 4.

The first loop returns 5 results for i, therefore runs 5 times.
the second returns only 4 results, so runs 4 times. I would suggest running your sequence starting at 0 to return 5 results as desired.

If you wanted your java code to mirror the second code, you should change it to:
int i = 1; i < 4.05 ; i+=1

To put it simply, you are running through a loop with different numbers, I suggest changing the second statement to start from 0.

Comment: I knew that, this was just an attempt, I want the thymeleaf to do the same as the Java code.

Comment: then you could change the thymeleaf code to 'numbers.sequence( 0, 4)'

Comment: the number 81 is out of 100, this number is actually some number from the model, i just typed it in hardcoded for readability

Comment: Well then keep the sequence from 0,81/20, i will give the same result. I cannot help you further than suggesting the correct starting number, starting from 0 will give you the results you need. The only reason it is giving incorrect number of loops is you are starting from a different number in each piece of code.

Answer (score 6):

The 1st value is the beginning of count, the 2nd is the maximum value and the 3rd is the incremental value

```
${#numbers.sequence( 1, 4, 1)}
```