# Simple for loop in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I add one variable to model called numberOfPages and I want to foor over this variable. I mean I want to achieve something like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633118/for-loop-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 2):

You may mean something like this:

```
<div th:each="pageNumber : ${numberOfPages}">
    <span th:text="${pageNumber}">Some default text here</span>
</div>
```

You can alternatively use the `th:block` and `th:remove="tag"` notation if you don't want tags to show.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for this:

```
<div th:each="page : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, __${numberOfPages}__)}">
    <span th:text="${page}">Some default text here</span>
</div>
```